# Do not understand a gitignore hint message

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to understand the following message:

```
cap@MacPro-2 wiki-dir % git add -A -- /Users/cap/DOCKER/dante-wiki/volumes/full/content/wiki-dir/extensions/DanteBread/breadCrumbs.js
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
extensions
hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addIgnoredFile false"
```

The issue I find confusing is the following:

Before I issued the `git add` command I got

```
cap@MacPro-2 wiki-dir % git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   extensions/DanteBread/COPYING

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   extensions/DanteBread/breadCrumbs.js
```

and afterwards I got

```
cap@MacPro-2 wiki-dir % git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   extensions/DanteBread/COPYING
    modified:   extensions/DanteBread/breadCrumbs.js
```

So Git in fact *did* add the added files to the staging area although I did not use `-force`.

Also, a separate `git check-ignore` suggests that the file is *not* ignored.

So why do I get this warning? And why does a `git add` claim that path `extensions` is ignored whereas `git check-ignore` does not find this?

Comment: Was git tracking those files before the path was put into .gitignore?

Comment: can you show the content of `.gitignore`?

Comment: @JimRedmond Yes, it was tracking those files. Maybe that is the reason?

Comment: .gitignore is not retroactive - it will not cause Git to forget about a file it already knows, and it says as much in the official docs - so that'd be my suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the same issue on my linux system, with git version 2.42.0. It looks like a bug (or a shortcoming) in git -- at least in its current version.

---

setup:

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
mkdir -p dir1
echo foobarfoobar > dir1/versioned.txt
git add dir1/versioned.txt && git commit -m "created dir1/versioned.txt"
echo dir1 > .gitignore
git add .gitignore && git commit -m "ignoring dir1"
```

now:

- running `git check-ignore dir1/versioned.txt` will yield an empty output, but running `git check-ignore dir1/ignored.txt` or even `git check-ignore dir1/doesnt_exist.txt` will show me that something is ignored:

```
# check-ignore does not mention versioned.txt: (coherent: that file is tracked)
$ git check-ignore dir1/versioned.txt

# it does catch ignored files, or even path that don't exist yet and are below dir1/:
# (coherent: these files would be ignored)
$ touch dir1/ignored.txt
$ git check-ignore dir1/ignored.txt
dir1/ignored.txt
$ git check-ignore dir1/doesnt_exist.txt dir1/no_dir/no_file.txt
dir1/doesnt_exist.txt
dir1/no_dir/no_file.txt

# running git check-ignore on the directory dir1 alone does not mention anything
# (shortcoming ? that path is explicitly mentioned as an ignored path,
#  it does have some of its content tracked though)
$ git check-ignore dir1/
```

- modifying the versioned file yields the same behavior as yours: the file is (correctly) listed in `git status`, and although it *does* get added I get the warning when running `git add` :

```
$ echo "barfoobarfoo" >> dir1/versioned.txt

$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   dir1/versioned.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

# (shortcoming: that file is known to be versioned, the warning
#  shouldn't be there)
$ git add dir1/versioned.txt
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
dir1
hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addIgnoredFile false"

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   dir1/versioned.txt
```

Comment: Nice write-up, but it does not answer the question. Just because your Linux version issues the same error does not mean that the message is by design and expected (which you seem to imply).

Comment: @j6t: point taken :) in my mind I obviously implied it was a bug ...

Answer (score 0):

I did some extensive testing and came to the following conclusions:

1. It looks like my mental model of gitignore / index / tracking was not correct.
2. It looks like the descriptions of how gitignore is working are bad, but with a bit of phantasy it looks like the behavior is correct.
3. The hint is wrong. The language "if you really want to add them" is, at least in my mind, pointing in the wrong direction.
4. My solution is now to turn off the hint.
5. The files had already been on the index and were not affected by the add.